# Button not reacted in nib.file

Tags: swift, button, alert, xib

I have a button in my nib(xib) file and when i klick in it it´s print nothing. I am new by xib.files, i think the Problem is in the xib. 
So the Button name is ButtomnTapped see it down in the code so when the Alert shows the ViewController and i klick the Button it must print "Showin"  but is´t print nothing. what can be the Problem hier ?? 
Thanks for your Help.

In my firstViewController to Show the TableViewAlertController:

```
    let AlertView = TableViewAlertController()
    let AlertTableView = SimpleAlert.Controller(view: AlertView.view, style: .Alert)
    showAlert(AlertTableView)
```

TableViewAlertController with the xib.file

```
import UIKit
import SimpleAlert

class TableViewAlertController: UIViewController {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
    subView = UIView()
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

convenience init() {
    self.init(nibName: "TableViewAlertController", bundle: nil)
}


@IBOutlet var subView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var BookTableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

@IBAction func ButtomnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Showin")
}
```

}